# Cannot invoke 'insert' with an argument list of type '(Character, atIndex: Int)'

Tags: swift

Why is Swift saying this?

My code:

```
var string: String = "Hello World"
string.insert("f", atIndex: 0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The index must be of type String.Index, so try replacing your code with this code.

```
var string: String = "Hello World"
string.insert("f", atIndex: advance(string.startIndex,0))
```